# API loop that inserts page parameter

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to work with the API documentation for an app.

In order to call it, I'm using the code:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://api.program.com/v1/notes?page=1&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx123xxx456xxx789xxx0001' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

The token is changed here for obvious reasons. But, what I'm really trying to setup involves the `page=1` parameter.

My question is two-fold:

1. How can I write a command that will capture all pages within the
   current structure of the command? So basically, after `page=1` it
   would then run `page=2`, `page=3`, ...
2. How can I do this in a way that also identifies when there are no more pages left, and thus, knows when to end running?

My current setup looks like this, but it's giving me what I need (I do not know this very well) plus I don't how to break out of the loop:

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++)); do
  curl -X GET \
  'https://api.program.com/v1/notes?page=1&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx123xxx456xxx789xxx0001' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
done
```

The result when there is no more records left looks like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "pageSize": 1000,
        "page": 65
    },
    "links": {
        "self": "/v1/conversations?page=65&pageSize=1000&sort=desc",
        "first": "/v1/conversations?page=1&pageSize=1000&sort=desc",
        "prev": "/v1/conversations?page=64&pageSize=1000&sort=desc",
        "next": null
    },
    "data": []
}
```

What I'm running per Charles Duffy's response - being saved as `test_run.sh`:

```
getPage () {
  curl -X GET 'https://api.test.com/v1/test?page="$1"&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9Cim97g123NXpMkS_Jc9xggCYlMQVvKsAeBCw' \
    -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
}
```

But that returns the error:

```
MacBook-Pro-8:~ admin$ ./test_run.sh
-bash: ./json_blob.sh: Permission denied
```

Yet when I run simply run the following straight in the command line, it returns the results fine:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.test.com/v1/test?page="$1"&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
        -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9Cim97g123NXpMkS_Jc9xggCYlMQVvKsAeBCw' \
        -H 'cache-control: no-cache' > test_run.json
```

Comment: Do you mean the `.data` field would be empty `[]` for the last page? Do you want the loop to happen for page 1,2..N

Comment: I though we already solved this yesterday. It looks like you have to iterate looking for the `next` page until there is no `next`.

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration you need to check if there is `"next" : null`, if found, break the loop.

```
while : ; do
  if [[ $(curl -X GET 'https://api.program.com/v1/notes?page=1&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx123xxx456xxx789xxx0001' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' | jq '.link.next') == 'null' ]] ; then
  break #Exit the loop
  fi 
done
```

Comment: Probably should `tee` the output to stdout, or else you're losing the original side effect of dumping the retrieved text. BTW, you can use `jq -e` to make its exit status reflect a conditional in the jq code, so you don't need the comparison against `null` to be done by the shell at all.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Question in follow-up: Let's say for the pages that have records (i.e. before the last page) I wanted to apply the following `jq` modifications: `jq -c '.data[] | .attributes | {text: .preview, from: .meta.from}' > data_json_blob.json` Would this be accomplished by adding an `else...` before the `break` portion where the loop exits? I would write the entirety of the code out, but I do not believe that I have room to do it in the comment section, but I imagine you can tell what I'm asking and can edit accordingly in your response if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what do you mean by `tee` the output?

Comment: Also, when I try to run your code, I am met with this error: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./conversation_data.sh: command substitution: line 5: `  | jq '.links.next''  it's formatting it weird, but I'm sure you can tell where the error ends

Comment: @gooponyagrinch, what I meant wrt. the need to use `tee` is that if there isn't a separate copy of the output from `curl` you can't actually *use* any of the content that's being downloaded, so this code does the work of downloading all the pages, but doesn't give the rest of your script a copy of what it downloaded. That can either be done by capturing the curl output to a variable and emitting it twice, or by putting the program `tee` inside the pipeline to make an extra copy, but one way or another it needs to be done for the script to be useful beyond meeting its narrow description.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, I'd probably write this more akin to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[12].*) echo "Bash 3.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

# Given a page number, return text of that page.
# Note that we switch from single to double quotes before expanding $1
getPage() {
  curl --fail -X GET 'https://api.program.com/v1/notes?page='"$1"'&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx123xxx456xxx789xxx0001' \
    -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
}

# return a stream with *all* page text, from page 1 until
# the first one with no .link.next.
getAllPages() {
  local page i=1
  while page=$(getPage "$i"); do
    printf '%s\n' "$page"
    if [[ $(jq '.links.next' <<<"$page") = null ]]; then
      break
    fi
    (( ++i ))
  done
}

getAllPages \
  | jq -c '.data[] | .attributes | {text: .preview, from: .meta.from}' \
  > data_json_blob.jsonl
```

The output file is named `.jsonl` here because it's in JSONLines format, not standard JSON. (You can't put multiple objects in a single JSON file without enclosing them in a list or other container and have it be valid; thus, when you feed a 1:1 `jq` transform more than one object on input, you typically get JSONL, not JSON, as output).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. May I ask: 1. What is that first line of code doing (`case $BASH_VERSION...`)? In addition to that, why is it `$1` instead of just `i` ?

Comment: The first line throws an error if you do something silly like try to run this script with `sh` instead of `bash`; it's sanity-checking for the runtime environment.

Comment: `$1` is used because it's bad form to rely on global variables spanning functions; using locally-scoped variables and function argument lists helps to keep your code self-contained, so you don't need to worry about some other function you call overwriting `$i` and changing behavior of something you didn't want it to.

Comment: @gooponyagrinch, ...btw, one item of note here is that you can test the individual pieces on their own. Run `getPage 1` and make sure it works, run `getPage 2` and make sure it works, run `getAllPages` and look at its output, etc; not using global variables means that `getPage` is self-contained so you don't need to do a bunch of setup before you can use it outside the context of the script it was written in, so the function definition can literally be copied-and-pasted to an interactive shell.

Comment: So it's weird, I'm running those tests as you mention, but for some reason when I run the initial `GET` command (curl --fail -X GET 'https://api.program.com/v1/notes?page='"$1"'&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx123xxx456xxx789xxx0001' \
    -H 'cache-control: no-cache') it works fine. But when I run it as getPage 1 {
  curl --fail -X GET 'https://api.program.com/v1/notes?page='"$1"'&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx123xxx456xxx789xxx0001' \
    -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
} it returns `Permission denied`?

Comment: Run `set -x` before your tests and record the trace logs emitted.

Comment: That said, `getPage 1 {...` is clearly invalid syntax. Copy and paste everything from the `getPage() {` to the `}` with no changes whatsoever, then just run `getPage 1` as its own command. Beyond that, I'd need to see a real log that hasn't been munged into a comment (and thus lost its line breaks and formatting) to debug further.

Comment: I just made some edits to the initial post to give you a better idea exactly what I'm running (outside of the URL and API key, which are obviously not real)

Comment: You need to use the quoting **exactly** as I gave it. The correct quoting, as in my answer, is `'...'"$1"'...'`; you changed it to `'..."$1"...'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188766/discussion-between-gooponyagrinch-and-charles-duffy).